# How to mix javascript and meteor to use youtube api

Tags: javascript, meteor, youtube

I am trying to implement the example youtube api html page described here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference in a meteor application.

I have read that you can use `Template.<template name>.rendered` to implement traditional javascript functionality within a meteor application.

So I attempted to implement that youtube example in meteor by putting it into a rendered function.

However No video will display.

I worry I am not understanding meteors capabilities. Is something like this even possible in meteor?

Code:

home.html:

```
enter code here
    <template name="home">
      <h1> Home</h1>
      This is the home page
      <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>
    <script>
    </script>
    </template>
```

home.js:

```
Template.home.rendered = function() {
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
}
```

P.s. I am aware of adrianliaw:youtube-iframe-api and do not want to use that. I would like a better understanding of how to implement this on my own. Hopefully doing so will further my knowledge of javascript and meteor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that after `https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api` loads, it will try to call the `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` function but it can't find it.  The code works if you change the functions to anonymous functions stored in variables that are available across the entire application.

home.html:

```
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> home}}
</body>

<template name="home">
  <h1> Home</h1>
  This is the home page
  <div id="player"></div>
</template>
```

home.js:

```
Template.home.rendered = function() {
      /* 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously. */
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      /* 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) */
      /*    after the API code downloads. */
      var player;
      onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      };

      /* 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready. */
      onPlayerReady = function(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      };

      /* 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes. */
      /*    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1), */
      /*    the player should play for six seconds and then stop. */
      var done = false;
      onPlayerStateChange = function(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      };
      stopVideo = function() {
        player.stopVideo();
      };
};
```

Notice the function declaration changes:

1. `function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` has been changed to
   `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function()`
2. `function onPlayerReady(event)` has been changed to `onPlayerReady
   = function(event)`
3. `function onPlayerStateChange(event)` has been changed to
   `onPlayerStateChange = function(event)`
4. `function stopVideo()` has been changed to `stopVideo = function()`

These global variables are now callable by the injected YouTube script.